# Term for (humorous) sentences that end in unexpected ways

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, humor, jokes

I'm trying to find the term that refers to a certain type of joke. These jokes generally have the following characterstics:

- generally only one sentence long
- the first half is straightforward and seems normal
- the second half is a bit abrupt and makes the reader/listener have to re-read/re-think the first part of the sentence, which now takes on a new meaning
- the new meaning is often humorous, but mainly only because it challenges the reader's original interpretation

One example of this is in *Friends*:  "If you want to receive emails about my upcoming shows, please give me money so I can buy a computer."

In it, the first part makes you assume that Phoebe will be talking about a link to a website, or something similar, but the second half tells you that she actually means something very different- perhaps not the best example, but it's the only famous one I can think of.

There are also some walks-into-a-bar jokes like this, such as: Four guys walk into a bar. The fifth guy marches in. Not one sentence, but the same idea.

I'm quite certain that there's a formal, stuffy-sounding one-word term for this.

Comment: Many one-liners have twists so they deliver more punch than length. Same with short stories.

Comment: What you describe sounds a little like "pull back and reveal". There is an explantion of this in the Guardian's article with the title "The comedian's toolbox": https://www.theguardian.com/books/2008/sep/22/comedy4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are perhaps describing a *paraprosdokian*. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian) explains, this is

> a figure of speech in which the latter part of a sentence, phrase, or larger discourse is surprising or unexpected in a way that causes the reader or listener to reframe or reinterpret the first part. It is frequently used for humorous or dramatic effect, sometimes producing an anticlimax. For this reason, it is extremely popular among comedians and satirists such as Groucho Marx.

Now that I search for it, the one that you mentioned, from *Friends*, is in [this](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/paraprosdokian-40-funny-sentences-you-wont-expect.html) list of paraprosdokians.

Is that suitably 'stuffy-sounding'? :)

---

The Wikipedia page linked above also references what are known as *[garden-path sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence)*, which are similar but at times require a bit more head-scratching to parse through. They generally rely more on grammatical and/or semantic nuances. (*[The horse raced past the barn fell](https://effectiviology.com/avoid-garden-path-sentences-in-your-writing/)*)

Comment: It is worth adding that this is another case where "the Greeks had a word for it".  The word relates to a type of joke in which a sentence that sets you up to expect one thing but ends up meaning something quite different.  'Prosdokia' (προσδοκια) means 'expectation' and the preposition 'para' (παρα) means 'beside' (both as in 'next to' and as in 'beside the point' or 'contrary to').  It takes the accusative case, so παρα προσδοκιαν meant 'contrary to expectation' and (as in English) could be fused into the word for a 'παραπροσδοκιαν' joke of which Aristophanes was the master.

Comment: Yes, thanks this is the word.